# Django REST Framework - Nested serializer not found

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework and noticing an issue with the nesting serializers. I'm being told that my serializer object isn't found. My code and traceback are below:

room/serializers.py

```
class RoomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = RoomTypeSerializer()
    clinic_location = serializers.Field(source='clinic_location')
    status = RoomStateTypeSerializer()
    url = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, default="room")

    class Meta:
        model = Room
```

visit/serializers.py

```
from clinic.serializers import *
from patient.serializers import *
from room.serializers import *
from service.serializers import *
from transition.serializers import *
from userprofile.serializers import *

class SubvisitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    visit = VisitSerializer()
    room = RoomSerializer()
    service = ServiceSerializer()
    transition = TransitionSerializer()
    status = SubVisitStateSerializer()
    patient = PatientSerializer()
    clinic_location = ClinicLocationSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Subvisit
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/Zee/Repos/patient-flow/visit/serializers.py" in SubvisitSerializer
  51.   room = RoomSerializer()
Exception Value: name 'RoomSerializer' is not defined
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,

Zee

Comment: Is your room serializer file `room/serializer.py` or `room/serializers.py`?. Mind the final s.

Comment: Good point, that was actually a typo when I made the post. I made the edit. Unfortunately that wasn't the problem although it could have been :)

Comment: @zee Try importing the serializers explicitly (which should be done anyway, since it's a good practice to follow) and see what happens (does it throw the same exception?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @dreysecat and @mariodev.

@mariodev, tried explicitly importing the serializer but didn't have any luck. It however ring a bell about my import statements, I think there was some kind of strange happening.

I moved the serializer to another location, and imported it from there. Took a bit of reading through the traceback, but realized there were a nested serializer that was causing the problem.

Thanks,

Zee